# In Description image not showing frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

In `Description image` not showing frontend

```
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" a.png"}}"="" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

I add description image in backend but frontend  it's not showing. Even i set File Permission also **777** But no result

Comment: Sorry I am not getting

Comment: where are you adding this image in text area?

Comment: `<img src="/media/wysiwyg/a.png" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">` you are using the textarea not static block so url is not rendering.

Comment: Ya it's working Y media url not working

Comment: add the answer kindly follow that for media url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add complete url of image

`<img src="/media/wysiwyg/a.png" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">`

With URl `Media` or `Skin` 
you have to use `getBlockTemplateProcessor()`

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($_product->getDescription()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code from

`<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" a.png"}}"="" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">`

to

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/a.png"}}" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

Comment: <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/a.png"}}" /> this is my backend url but front end it automatically change

Comment: @MagentoDev I believe you are not doing it correctly please see here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5045/21339

Comment: Let me explain i add one textarea attribute there i add image <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/a.png"}}" /> then i call front end there it's not showing show i check inspect element it show in this way  <img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" a.png"}}"="" alt="" data-pin-nopin="true">